# Issues with getting UR

Tags: voltage, resistors, amperage, calculation

I'm trying to get UR5 from this schema, but something is not right.

All I have so far[image: Schema]
[image: data]

[image: data]

[image: calculation]

[image: calculation]

[image: I'm looking for this value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a weakness that I need to redraw the circuit in a way that is easier to understand:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNrfj8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R216 = R2+R1+R6 = 130 ohm

R21635 = R216 || R3 || R5 = 15.15 ohm

And the resistance of all the resistors combined is

R216354 = R21635 + R4 = 75.15 ohm

The current through all the resistors combined is

I = E1 / R216354 = 20 / 75.15 = 0.266 A

Since all of the current goes through R4, we can find U4

UR4 = I*R4 = 0.266 * 60 = 16.0 volts

Then

UR5 = E1 - UR4 = 4 volts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an arithmetic problem: -

[image]

> *I'm trying to get UR5 from this schema*

So (R1+R2+R6) || R3 || R5 = 15.14563 Ω and not 15 Ω.

Then it's just a simple potential divider with the 15.14563 Ω and R4.

Hence, UR5 = 4.031 volts

Comment: thank you for your feedback